# Passing arguments with escape characters to a batch file from PowerShell prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file which runs a Python package, and it takes a string argument to run. The string, usually a Youtube link, has assignment symbols (`=`) so the argument must be enclosed in quotation marks to work properly. And it does work fine when I call it from command prompt like so (the file's path is set in environment variables so it can be called directly with its name):

```
script-name "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH_CthENcPCM0Dww6a5XYC7f"
```

This command works fine on CMD prompt, as I said, but on PowerShell everything after `=` symbol is discarded. How can I get this batch file to work properly in PowerShell prompt, which is my go to terminal?

`script-name.bat` file itself looks like this:

```
youtube-dl -r 1500K -o "D:\Downloads\Youtube Videos\%%(playlist)s\%%(autonumber)02d - %%(title)s.%%(ext)s" %1
```

Edit: The command and output clearly shows how the rest of the link is discarded:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dl-playlist "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH_CthENcPCM0Dww6a5XYC7f"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>youtube-dl -r 1500K -o "D:\Downloads\Youtube Videos\%(playlist)s\%(autonumber)02d - (ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list
```

Comment: Have you tried using a single quite instead of double quotes

Comment: @Jawad yes, same result, unfortunately

Comment: did you try putting the url in some varible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From PowerShell, [escape](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) double quotes as follows:

```
dl-playlist "`"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH_CthENcPCM0Dww6a5XYC7f`""
```

or

```
dl-playlist '"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH_CthENcPCM0Dww6a5XYC7f"'
```

or

```
dl-playlist `""https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH_CthENcPCM0Dww6a5XYC7f"`"
```

or even

```
dl-playlist """https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlA0Gpn_vH_CthENcPCM0Dww6a5XYC7f"""
```

Comment: Huh, did not expect something this simple. Why the difference between the two shells though? Any idea?